# Not getting the value of href when loading HTML as string

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I am trying to load HTML string into puppeteer and get all `<link>` tags. But I am getting the empty set of `<links` when there are `<link>` tags with the `href` value in the HTML string.

I copied the HTML code as string from : `view-source:https://redis.io/` and extracted the strings as:

```
    async function main() {
        const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ["--no-sandbox"]});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setContent(html);

        await page.screenshot({path:"s.png"});
        const links = await page.$$eval('link', links => links.map(link => link.href))

        const singleLink = await page.$eval('link', link => link.href);
        console.log(singleLink)
        console.log(links);

        browser.close();
}

main()
        .then(() => {})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

But I get the empty list of `links` . What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

`href` is an `anchor`'s property. If you want to get the `href` from a `link` element, you will need to use `getAttribute`.

```js
const links = await page.$$eval('link', links => links.map(link => link.getAttribute('href')))
```

Comment: It works absolutely fine if I load the HTML using `page.goto`

Comment: Would you know the difference?

Comment: That could be related to the fact that those links are in the head. Maybe Chrome reacts differently when you inject the HTML

Comment: Keep in mind that setContent is nothing more than a javascript function doing document.open();
document.write(html);
document.close();